# Deruny, deruni or deryni?

Tags: english, phonetics, transliteration

What is the correct spelling of potato pancakes, If we take the Russian or Ukrainian origin of the word? Deruny, deruni or deryni?
A google search for the etymology says  [deryny](https://bibleoftaste.com/2020/06/24/potato-pancake/)

And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_pancake):

> Potato pancakes, raggmunk, deruny, latkes or boxties are shallow-fried
> pancakes of grated or ground potato, matzo meal or flour and a binding
> ingredient such as egg or applesauce, often flavored with grated
> garlic or onion and seasoning.

But this spelling gives a sound [i:], which is wrong.

Comment: English doesn't allow final [ɪ], instead we have the hapPY vowel [i] (normally it has the quality of FLEECE, but the length of KIT), so any English romanisation will suggest a form ending in [i], rather than [ɪ]

Comment: Are these what the Russians call драники?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fits better at [ukrainian.se]. We also have tag [`transliteration`](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transliteration) for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an English word listed in either the Oxford English Dictionary or Merriam-Webster's dictionary so there is no official "correct" spelling. It is a [Ukrainian word](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8), Деруни. The letter "і" is standardly transliterated as *i*, whereas "и" varies according to particular convention between "i" and "y" or "ȳ", "y" being the most common. The most standard transliteration is "deruny", which is also the most frequent w.r.t. Google hits. But to take a word that *is* English, there isn't even a correct spelling of theatre/theater, so the idea of "correct spelling" is misconceived. There is nothing linguistically wrong with deryni or even depuhi, it's just that these are more likely to mislead people as to how the author wants readers to pronounce the word.